# Can't post bounty on a per-site child meta

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, bounties, stackexchange-2.0, per-site-meta

I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/cant-place-a-bounty-on-meta-questions), which shows when this Meta gained the ability to post bounties. However, this doesn't work on per-child meta sites.

I realise there's a problem in that rep is copied from the main site, but is there no other way we can allow for bounties to be posted? Especially for a site in early beta stage it's really useful to be able to bring further attention to some questions.

Comment: See this feature request: [Bounty-like feature on metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231215/241697)

Answer (score 5):

[All per site metas don't have reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/13992)

Comment: I pointed this out in my question (that's what I was getting at by saying "rep is copied from the main site"). However, that link doesn't explain why there's still no workaround to posting bounties. The blog post reference just says "bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta".

Comment: @marcog Why would you want to make a bounty on a per-site meta anyway?

Comment: @dabp Same reason people post bounties here. It acts as flagging important questions to give them more attention.

Comment: @marcog Thaty's what the featured tag is for.

Comment: @badp Oh! I was unaware of that. Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Except that the featured tag is mod-only

Answer (score 2):

There is no bounty system on per-site metas because *per-site metas have no reputation system*.

Meaning, your rep on the per-site meta is the same as your rep on the parent site.

Comment: But a user should be able to forfeit some main-site rep in favor of the bounty recipient's main-site rep.