# Why didn't this user get any reputation for an accepted answer?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, accepted-answer

A [user on Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3570482#3570482) noticed that on a [question on Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/what-patents-do-i-need-to-buy-or-lease-to-make-and-sell-an-electric-guitar-to-th), the user whose answer was accepted didn't get the +15 reputation associated with it:

[image]

...but however the reputation *is* listed in their [reputation tab](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/14387/yolktern?tab=reputation&sort=post):

[image]

According to their reputation tab, they should have 56 reputation on Ask Patents, but however they only have 41.
I looked around and found [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/why-did-i-not-receive-15-rep-for-an-accepted-answer) but however, their account is registered and active, and so is the account of the asker, unlike the case in the aforementioned question.

I thought caching might be to blame, but however surely caching shouldn't affect reputation changes on the same site ([as seen on child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/why-is-the-meta-reputation-derived-directly-from-the-parent-site)).

Comment: Anna Lear: I don't get how this is 'no repro'; this issue still exists, the +15 reputation still isn't reflected. As of this moment, the user should have 76 reputation.

Comment: It doesn't. I see 35 rep there for the answer. 20 for upvotes, 15 for an accept (3 events, in total). This is in your screen shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have 61 reputation as of right now and everything in their rep audit looks correct.

They had another post (now deleted) that picked up offensive flags and resulted in a -15 reputation drop, which possibly gives the illusion of the +15 from accepted answer not getting awarded.